# How to create a Scatter Plot chart in SSRS 2008?

Tags: ssrs-2008, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot chart in SSRS 2008 (not 2008 R2).  Is this possible?  I want to map military time of day for each day that an event occurs.  So my data looks like:

```
Hour of Day       Day of the Week  
8                       3
14                     5
2                       1
5                        1
10                      7
```

But right now it just sums the HOur of Day values.  I want each of them as discreet values however.  (Day of the week is 1-7 = Sunday-Saturday).

If this is possible, then how do I set this up?